# Synchronize data between two database servers with python

Tags: python, postgresql, synchronization, data-consistency

I have two postgres database connections with two databases.
The databases are the same with the same schemas and tables.

I'm using python and i'm writing script that executes some database operations.

My question is how can i handle data consistency when data is pushed to the databases and if for example one of the databases is offline at the moment of pushing.

At the end the dead database must be up to date.